# Math calculation in Java

Tags: java, math

I am working on a simple program to calculate a mathematical equation. But there is a problem that I could not find. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

It seems a problem is with

```
alpha[j] = (double)(j-1)*2*Math.PI/(double)rotationNum;
```

NullPointerException is returned. There has to be some silly mistakes here.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
//import Jama.Matrix;

class efun {
    static double epso;
    static double sigma;
    static double alpha[];
    static double charge;
    static double axisR;
    static double axisZ;
    //static Random randGen;
    static int numPoints = -1;
    static int rotationNum;


    public static void main (String[] args) {
        try {
            sigma = 300e-6*1e2; 
            epso = 8.854e-12; 

            /*Input arguments*/
            numPoints = Integer.parseInt (args[0]);
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(args[1]);
            rotationNum = Integer.parseInt (args[2]);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);         
            double pointsR[] = new double[numPoints];
            double pointsZ[] = new double[numPoints];
            double chargeDensity[] = new double[numPoints];
            double electricField = 0.0;
            double ER = 0.0;
            double EZ = 0.0;
            double EY = 0.0;

            for (int id = 0; id < numPoints; id++) {
                // read file
                while ( (line = br.readLine() )!= null) {
                    StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(line);
                    axisR = Double.parseDouble(stk.nextToken());
                    axisZ = Double.parseDouble(stk.nextToken());
                    charge = Double.parseDouble(stk.nextToken());

                    pointsR[id] = axisR;
                    pointsZ[id] = axisZ;
                    chargeDensity[id] = charge;
                    System.out.println("axisR: "+pointsR[id]+" and axisZ: "+ pointsZ[id]+"; its corresponding charge density is: "+ chargeDensity[id]);

                    double rotatedR[] = new double[numPoints];
                    double rotatedZ[] = new double[numPoints];
                    double rotatedY[] = new double[numPoints];
                    double sumSquarePoints[] = new double[numPoints];

                    for (int j = 1; j < rotationNum+1; j++) {                   
                        alpha[j] = (double)(j-1)*2*Math.PI/(double)rotationNum; 
                        System.out.println("print alpha: "+alpha[j]);
                        rotatedR[id] = pointsR[id] - Math.cos(alpha[j])*pointsR[id];
                        rotatedZ[id] = pointsZ[id];
                        rotatedY[id] = pointsR[id] - Math.sin(alpha[j])*pointsR[id];

                        sumSquarePoints[id] = Math.sqrt(rotatedR[id]*rotatedR[id] + rotatedZ[id]*rotatedZ[id] + rotatedY[id]*rotatedY[id]);

                        ER += chargeDensity[id]*rotatedR[id]/(sumSquarePoints[id]*sumSquarePoints[id]*sumSquarePoints[id]);
                        EZ += chargeDensity[id]*rotatedZ[id]/(sumSquarePoints[id]*sumSquarePoints[id]*sumSquarePoints[id]);
                        EY += chargeDensity[id]*rotatedY[id]/(sumSquarePoints[id]*sumSquarePoints[id]*sumSquarePoints[id]);

                        System.out.println ("ER is: "+ ER);
                        System.out.println ("EZ is: "+ EZ);
                        System.out.println ("EY is: "+ EY);
                    }
                }
            }

            electricField = sigma/(4*Math.PI*epso)*Math.sqrt(ER*ER + EZ*EZ + EY*EY); 
            System.out.println("electricField is: " + electricField);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the stacktrace tell you?

Comment: NullPointerException is returned as stated in the question.

Comment: Have you defined `alpha` ? Also the stacktrace has more info than just NPE.. it has a line number apart from other info.

Comment: Just glancing at the code this `for (int j = 1; j < rotationNum+1; j++){` looks odd. Why `rotationNum+1`. Are you confident that's what you meant to do? Again not looking at it hard so may well be completely fine.

Comment: It is ok. It can be either j=0; j<rotationNum or the one above. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class variable `alpha` is declared, but not initialized, so Java gives it the default value of `null`.  The variable was never initialized to any array.

```
static double alpha[];
```

However, it doesn't look like you're using any other intended value in the array except for the current value.  Just declare it to be a local `double` (not an array), and use it as a normal variable.

```
double alpha = (double)(j-1)*2*Math.PI/(double)rotationNum;
```

And use `alpha` instead of `alpha[j]` a few lines down from there.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also thanks for every one who has input here!!

Answer (score 2):

You never initialized alpha, you only declared it, so you can't access `alpha[j]`. Initialize it and make sure that its size is large enough for every j:

```
alpha = new double[MY_SIZE];
```

Also, make sure that you're passing in at least 3 arguments to main so that rotationNum is assigned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You've never initialized `alpha[]`. Just like `pontsR, pointsZ, and chargeDensity`, you need to point `alpha` at a new array of doubles before you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `alpha = new double[rotationNum ];` after getting `rotationNum`